# How to convert unsigned char * to byte array in cli/c++

Tags: arrays, pointers, char, byte, unsigned

I know how to convert byte array to unsigned char *. How can I do the reverse? 
**I don't know the length of the unsigned char *.**

I am trying to do thinks like--

```
unsigned char *ptr_data = "The size of this value is unknown";
System::IntPtr ptr = (System::IntPtr)ptr_data;
System::String^ str_data = Marshal::PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
array<Byte>^ bytes = System::Text::Encoding::->GetBytes(str_data);
```

Comment: You can't. You have to keep his size when you do a malloc.

Comment: @kobootor did you manage to succeed ? I am now also trying to figure it out